# Autómata Finito Determinista en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, array

Hola a todos muy buenas tardes, el dia de hoy tengo una duda muy simple como puedo hacer que mi arreglo en python acepte cadenas de valores en vez de enteros.
para que se entienda mejor lo que quiero realizar con mi AFD dejare el siguiente codigo:

```
# llamamos a la libreria "regular expresions"
import re 

#Definimos funcion caracter 
def caracter(character):
    global simbolo
    simbolo=""
    global Fin
    Fin=""
    a="a"
    b="b"
    c="c"

    #comparamos si es a o no
    if(re.match(a,character)):
        simbolo="  A  "
        return 0
    else:#comparamos si es b o no
        if(re.match(b,character)):
            simbolo="  B  "
            return 1
        else:#comparamos si es c o no
            if(re.match(c,character)):
                simbolo="  C  "
                return 2
            else:
                if(character==Fin):
                    return 3

        #si no es a,b,c entonces no entra
        print("Error el ",character,"no es valido")
        exit()

#definimos al la funcion  encabezado
def encabezado():
    print("""|  Edo. Actual |Caracter | Simbolo|Edo. Siguiente |""")

#definimos la funcion contenido donde guarda cada valor despues de encontrarlo en un ciclo
def contenido(estadosig,character,simbolo,estado):
    print("|     ",estadosig,"      |  ",character,"    |",simbolo," |     ",estado,"       |")

#MAIN
#Este es la tabla de transiciones del automata AFD creado
tabla=[
[1,5,3],
[3,2,7],
[4,1,7],
[3,3,3],
[4,4,4],
[6,3,8],
[5,4,8],
[7,7,7],
[8,8,8]]
estado = 0

print ("ingresa la cadena ")
cadena = input()
encabezado()

#ciclo para recorrer la cadena
for  character in cadena:

    estadosig=estado

    #llamamos al metodo para saber si es un caracter valido y el valor retornado se guarda en charcaracter
    charcaracter= caracter(character)

    #guardamos en estado el valor obtenido en la tabla segun las cordenadas que recibio anteriormente
    estado=tabla[estado][charcaracter]

    #Si el valor obtenido es una E imprimimos cadena no valida

    contenido(estadosig,character,simbolo,estado)

#al concluir si el estado no es 3 que es el de aceptacion imprimimos cadena no valida    
if(estado<7):
        print("""|                     No Valida                   |
+-------------------------------------------------+""")

#si el estado es 3 es una cadena de aceptacion
if(estado>=7):
    print("|     ",estado,"      |         |  FND   |               |")
    print("""|                       Valida                    |
+-------------------------------------------------+""")
```

pero lo que quier es evitar los enteros de mi arreglo es decir esta parte:

```
#MAIN
#Este es la tabla de transiciones del automata AFD creado
tabla=[
[1,5,3],
[3,2,7],
[4,1,7],
[3,3,3],
[4,4,4],
[6,3,8],
[5,4,8],
[7,7,7],
[8,8,8]]
estado = 0
```

y saber como sustituir la por algo como esto:

```
tabla=[
["R1","S1","U1"],
["U1","R1","V1"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],]
estado = 0
```

sin embargo si lo dejo de esta manera: me produce el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

entiendo que mi arreglo solo permite valores ***integer*** y no valores de cadena pero pues no se como puedo hacer para que acepta las cadena.
espero haberme hecho entender. gracias y buen dia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una confusión, el arreglo (array) permite cualquier tipo de valor, los índices a los arreglos SI deben ser enteros:

```
tabla = ["Hola", "Mundo"]
print(tabla[0]) # Esto funciona bien "Hola"

print(tabla["quiero el 2do"]) # Esto da error
```

El problema es que cuando haces esto:

```
estado=tabla[estado][charcaracter]
```

es necesario que `estado` sea un entero (`charcaracter` lo es), la primera vez, funcionaría por que has inicializado en 0 esta variable, pero el índice apuntará a un valor tipo cadena, por lo que en definitva estarías haciendo, por ejemplo:

```
estado=tabla["ETC"][charcaracter]
```

Lo cual efectivamente es inválido. Si lo que buscas es mostrar un estado más descriptivo lo podrías hacer teniendo un array paralelo de traducción que debiera ser idéntico al tamaño de `tabla` (en el ejemplo que pegaste no lo es).

```
tabla_descripcion=[
["R1","S1","U1"],
["U1","R1","V1"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"],
["ETC","ETC","ETC"]]
```

Y a la hora de obtener el estado, obtenemos también la descripción del mismo

```
estado=tabla[estado][charcaracter]
estado_descripcion=tabla_descripcion[estado][charcaracter]
```